# Injecting 32bit dll into 64bit process - Autoit makes it possible?

Tags: c++, dll, code-injection, autoit

afaik there is no way to inject 32bit dlls into 64bit processes and vice versa (at least it's not possible with my c++ written injector / dll). However, when using the Autoit injector from http://pastebin.com/AGWw2kT8 it is possible to inject 32bit dlls into 64bit processes. This Autoit library uses the same way of injecting as my c++ injector (CreateRemoteThread). Can someone explain this behaviour?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this doesn't work.

Comment: This is the Arthur C Clarke effect. Injecting 32-bit DLLs into 64-bit processes is not possible.  The lack of error checking in that script can certainly make it look like it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the reason why the injection was successful. In the Autoit injection test script I use `@SystemDir & "\calc.exe"` as path for the target application. However, on a 64bit Windows installation the `@SystemDir` macro points to C:\Windows\SysWOW64 instead of C:\Windows\System32 - therefore the script started the 32bit version of calc.exe, in which the injection succeeded.

Answer (score 2):

`CreateRemoteThread 32->64` won't work!

`CreateRemoteThread 64->32` will work!

More info on that subject [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/10/20/9006720.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

It can't possibly work (you can't mix 32 and 64 bit code in one process). Therefore it doesn't. It may of course fail to make it clear that it hasn't worked.

Comment: You certainly *can* mix 32-bit and 64-bit code in one process. See: Heaven's Gate